# Problem with Mysql index when using "OR" statement

Tags: mysql, indexing, filesort

Is there any way how to create an functioning index for this query and to get rid of "filesort"?

```
SELECT id, title FROM recipes use index (topcat) where
(topcat='$cid' or topcat2='$cid' or topcat3='$cid') 
and approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,10;
```

I created index "topcat" ( columns: topcat1+topcat2+topcat3+approved+id) but still ge "Using where; Using filesort".

I can create one more column, lets say, "all_topcats" to store topcat numbers in an array - 1,5,7 and then to run query "... where $cid iIN ()...". But the probem is that in this case "all_topcats" column will be "varchar" but "approved" and "id" columns - int, and index will not be used anyway.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might improve performance for that query if you reordered the columns in the index:

```
approved, topcat1, topcat2, topcat3, id
```

It would be useful to know what the table looks like and why you have three columns named like that. It might be easier to organise a good query if you had a subsidiary table to store the topcat values, with a link back to the main table, but without knowing why you have it set up like that it's hard to know whether that would be sensible.

Can you post the `CREATE TABLE`?

### Edit in response to user message

Your table doesn't sound like it's well-designed. The following design would be better: Add two new tables, `Category` and `Category_Recipe` (a cross-referencing table). `Category` will contain a list of your categories and `Category_Recipe` will contain two columns, one a foreign key to `Category` and one a foreign key to the existing `Recipe` table. A row of `Category_Recipe` is a statement "this recipe is in this category". You will then be able to very simply write a query that will search for recipes in a given category. You also have the ability to put a recipe in arbitrarily many categories, rather than being limited to 3. Look up "database normalisation" and "foreign keys".

Comment: Hammerite, this table is being used by a script called "Kitchen recipes". Each recipe can belong to (up to) 3 categories. So there are 3 columns for possible 3 categories. If I access, for example, category "Main dishes" with id, for example, 6, the query scans all 3 columns to check if the id  6 exists in column 1 or column 2 or column 3. I can post CREATE TABLE but I don't think that this can be useful.

Comment: Thank you, Hammerite. I created additional tables as you suggested. Now everything looks OK and there is no need for "and approved='1' in the query because unapproved records don't exist in category tables.